# Add text value to jquery function (var)

Tags: jquery

How can I add input text variable(value) to function(var description) ?

```
$(".update").click(function()
{
var article_id=$(this).attr("article_id");
var description=$(this).attr("description");
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "conf.php",
    data: {
    article_id: article_id,
    description: description,
    },..

<a href="javascript:;" class="update" article_id="$id">Description</a><input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I actually need only value from Input type="text". var description=$(this).next("input").val(); tried this but not working

Comment: Then value is passed it not defined

Comment: A little mistake by me. Everything works fine. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
$(".update").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // do not follow the link
  var article_id=$(this).attr("article_id");
  var description=$(this).next("input").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow,

```
var description=$(this).attr("description") + $(this).siblings('input[type=text]').val();
```

Comment: Why? - `$(this).next("input")` is much shorter